# Android segmentation fault when running on console

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, segment

I have a shared library a.so and used both release/debug version successfully within an APK. And I write several unit test for a.so but I got Segmentation fault when the test program trying to load the **release version** shared library. Even I did nothing in the test file, it also crashes.
But the **debug version** works fine. And this problem only happens on emulator when I tested it on a device it's fine. 
So what are the possible root causes for this? Is there any tool to debug this when running on console?

Comment: the segmentation fault is usually because the initial emory allocated it is collected, free already and you try to accesing

Comment: You can run the native process through lldb or gdb. Or you can look for crash log